# PHP CSV Upload - Merge On Same Order Number

Tags: php, csv

I need a bit of help, I have a script I have just created, but I have just noticed that there are multiple lines in the CSV that need merging and the values adding together

For example - the CSV has 21 rows (I only use 3 of the rows)

`ORDER_ID - SHIPPING_COST - SHIPPING_METHOD
1234        10.99          Standard
1234        12.99          Standard
1235        9.99           Express
1235        1.00           Express
1235        5.99           Express
1236        6.95           Standard
1237        6.95           Standard`

Now when i load the CSV I want the order_ID's to merge so for example order 1234 should have a total value of 23.98.

My full code is:

```
<code>
<?php
    // path where your CSV file is located
    $csv_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/script/J5HUH/dhl/upload/" . "NCL8436151.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    $theData = fgets($csvfile);
    $i = 0;
    $dhl_total = 0;
    $our_total = 0;

    while (!feof($csvfile)) {
        $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
        $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
        $insert_csv = array();
        $insert_csv['invoice'] = $csv_array[0];
        $insert_csv['date'] = $csv_array[1];
        $insert_csv['company'] = $csv_array[2];
        $insert_csv['account'] = $csv_array[3];
        $insert_csv['line'] = $csv_array[4];
        $insert_csv['product'] = $csv_array[5];
        $insert_csv['PAL'] = $csv_array[6];
        $insert_csv['gross_charge'] = $csv_array[7];
        $insert_csv['nett_charge'] = $csv_array[8];
        $insert_csv['weight'] = $csv_array[9];
        $insert_csv['discount'] = $csv_array[10];
        $insert_csv['discount_code'] = $csv_array[11];
        $insert_csv['discount_ammount'] = $csv_array[12];
        $insert_csv['discount_code'] = $csv_array[13];
        $insert_csv['tax'] = $csv_array[14];
        $insert_csv['tax_code'] = $csv_array[15];
        $insert_csv['awb'] = $csv_array[16];
        $insert_csv['order_num'] = $csv_array[17];
        $insert_csv['ship_date'] = $csv_array[18];
        $insert_csv['origin'] = $csv_array[19];
        $insert_csv['destination'] = $csv_array[20];
        $insert_csv['shipper_details'] = $csv_array[21];
        $insert_csv['receiver'] = $csv_array[22];
        $order = $insert_csv['order_num'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `base_shipping_amount`,`shipping_method`,`base_grand_total` FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE `increment_id`='$order'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $x++; 
        $class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'graybackground';
        echo "<tr class='$class'>";
        echo "<td>" . $insert_csv['order_num'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>&pound;" .number_format($row[2],2). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $insert_csv['product'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row[1]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>&pound;" . number_format($insert_csv['nett_charge'],2) . "</td>";
        if($row[0] < $insert_csv['nett_charge']){
            echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\">&pound;" . number_format($row[0],2) . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>&pound;" . number_format($row[0],2) . "</td>";    
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $dhl_total += $insert_csv['nett_charge'];
        $our_total += $row[0];
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($csvfile);

    echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";

    $mag_total = $our_total/2;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid #fff;"></td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid #fff;"></td>';
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid #fff;"></td>';
    echo '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;"></td>';
    echo "<td><strong>&pound;".number_format($dhl_total,2)."</strong></td>";
    if($dhl_total < $our_total){
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\"><strong>&pound;".number_format($mag_total,2)."</strong></td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td>&pound;<strong>".number_format($mag_total,2)."</strong></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
</code>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk - I need to get it to merge rows with the same "order_num" to total up the complete prices.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk I'm struggling to try and figure out how to do this, trying to get my head around it. Somehow do another loop inside the foreach to look through the array for the same order_num?